# ARInvoice.CustomerLocationID

Tags: acumatica

The ARInvoice DAC has a field CustomerLocationID.  The SQL table ARInvoice does not have a field CustomerLocationID.  I have created a SQL View to create a custom DAC from and I need to set the CustomerLocationID from an invoice, in the SQL View,  equal to a value to return the correct results.  What SQL table holds the field ARInvoice.CustomerLocationID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARInvoice herits from ARRegister Class which contains CustomerLocationID field.

Because ARInvoice uses this field it is declared as new abstract in it's class definition:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Views is against Acumatica Standard. It is recommended that you create a DAC that is a PXProjection.

[Here](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/03/pxprojection-sql-views-using-bql.html) is an asiablog post about them.

You can find the LocationID in BAccount.
Select the BAccount where the BAccountID is equal to the CustomerID of the Invoice. The field is DefLocationID.

Use the BAccountR DAC to prevent caching issues.